# Как обращаться к экземлярам класса через НАЗВАНИЕ_КЛАССA.[i].экземляр?

Tags: c++, классы

такая заморочка с классами. Описываю класс Работник.
Как привязать класс к массиву в основной программе? Чтобы мог обращаться к экземлярам класса через `НАЗВАНИЕ_КЛАССA.[i].экземляр`.

У меня класc Employee

```
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
std:: string lastname; 
std:: string initials; 
std:: string position;
int receiptYear,i=5;
double salary;
std::cout<<"Введите фамилию работника";
std::cin>>famName;
std::cout<<"Введите инициалы работника";
std::cin>>initials;
std::cout<<"Введите должность работника";
std::cin>>position;
std::cout<<"Введите год поступления на работу";
std::cin>>Year;
std::cout<<"Зарплата";
std::cin>>salary;
}
```

Крч, вот этот ввод должен осуществляться как бы в массив, а не единично например

```
std::cin>>Employee[i].salary;
```

Comment: Какой хотя язык программирования. приведите пример вашего класса и ту часть "основной программы", где вы хотите обращаться к нему.

Comment: вот смотрите теперь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно что-то наподобие (если я верно понял ваши затруднения):

```
// Тип
struct Employee {
    string lastname; 
    string initials; 
    string position;
    double salary;
};

// Массив
Employee e[100];

// Ваша работа с элементами массива:
cin >> e[5].salary;
```

Answer (score 0):

Где то так, наверное:

```
Employee employees[100];
//...
std::cin >> name;
employees[i].setName(name);
```